# Read Flash Cookie from javascript or ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, flash, swt

We have a flash video that was created for our project, we dont the source so we have to work around the compiled flash file.  We are going to host the video on our domain and the video creates a sol cookie (flash cookie) file to store how far the user has proceeded though the video.  So my plan is to access this cookie to see how far the user has progressed and then fire an event when they have finished the movie.

I have been googling for some help but haven't found to much. I have found out that its possible to do in javascript and I have found some .net sol file viewers but haven't seen any examples I can get my mind around.

I have watched the traffic that gets created with fiddler and every time the next button is clicked a new request is fired with the swt file that is being accessed. I would also be happy with tracking every time one of these swt files has been accessed as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with flash, but I'm sure you need to build another flash-movie(those shared objects can only be accessed from flash-movies).
So what you need is your own flash-movie embedded in the page, that reads the 'cookie' and transfers the data to javascript.

Comment: I've been reading this article http://magp.ie/2010/03/22/javascript-externalinterface-flash-and-local-shared-objects/ on SWFobjects http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/. It looks like you can create and read flash cookies though the SWF file itself though javascript but haven't figured it all out yet.